# Boolean "!" Java

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I need some clarification.

So if someone does:

```
boolean something = false;
```

and then they do:

```
while(!something){
}
```

what exactly is that '!' telling the while to do?

also what is the if statement condition if its

```
if(!something)
```

Comment: negation of predicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` means not.

If you you use `!` it'll print reverse of it.

Like if you use `!something`  it'll print `true`.

Your code

```
if(!something)
```

If statements execute when the condition evaluates to `true` .

In order to make it `true`, we use `!` to inverse the result to `true`.

Comment: The last two lines of this answer don't make sense.  The answer is correct but it's meaning may be lost due to the grammatical errors.

Comment: @LukePark sorry mate  during your editing , i was also editing . But i have added your parts.

Comment: Not a problem, it makes sense now so that's the main thing!

Answer (score 3):

`!` is the same as a boolean NOT.  Placing a `!` in front of a conditional expression will reverse the current value.  E.g. `true` becomes `false` and `false` becomes `true`.  Additionally, easily Google searchable.

Comment: Upvoted for being the first Answer to prominently use word "NOT" ... which is something that newbies are much more like to understand than tech-speak like "boolean negation operator" or "inverts the value of the boolean".

Answer (score 2):

The ! symbol means the inverse of something, or NOT something. In java, this is usually applied to Boolean methods and variables to specifically exclude whatever you are attaching it to, or to refer to the opposite. In your case, "something" is stated as false, placing the "!" in front of it makes it true so your while loop will run until "something" is made false again. Same thing happens in your if condition, since Boolean data types are usually only true or false, the ! tells the while loop "Hey this is the opposite of what it is" which is true, so the condition passes and the code in the loop will run.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!something) {
...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
while (something == false) {
...
}
```

Similarly for an if statement

It can be read in english as "not something"

Answer (score 0):

`!` is the [Logical Complement Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html), which inverts the value of a boolean.  It basically means "not" when describing that code.  So:

```
while (!something)
```

means "while not something".  So this:

```
boolean something = false;
while (!something)
```

equals this:

```
boolean something = true;
while (something)
```

Or, to put it another way:

```
true == !false
```

Answer (score 0):

`!` stands for negation. Loops or `if` statement in Java will evaluate only when condition is `true`. `!` is used when you want to perform some operation when something is not `true`.

Answer (score 0):

! is the reverse. So if your variable something  is set to false, then !something  = true.

The while executes "while the condition is true". So your code will run forever. Unless inside you change something = true, and then, in the evaluation, !something = true, so the condition is not true and the loop ends

Same goes for the if, if the condition is true it will execute what it's inside. Otherwise it will skip that part

Answer (score 0):

The `!` operator inverts the meaning of any expression that returns a boolean.

Java does have `boolean` as a primitive type for the language, so, if any expression (whether that be a literal, variable or method call) is/returns a boolean then the `!` unary prefix operator is usable:

- `!false`;
- `!someVariableWhichIsABoolean`;
- `!someMethodWhichReturnsABoolean`;
- `!someObjectReference.callingSomeMethodWhichReturnsABoolean()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` operator "reverse" the operand (`true` -> `false` and `false` -> `true`), **but it does not change the variable's value**.

For instance,

```
boolean bool = false;
```

And then I have another variable:

```
boolean bool2 = !bool;
```

`bool2` is `true` while `bool` is still `false`. It's like the `+` operator:

```
int i = 0;
int j = i + 1;
```

In this case, `i`'s value is not 1, right? But `j` is 1.

So

```
while (!bool)
```

is the same as

```
while (true)
```

because `bool` is `false`.

Similarly,

```
if (!bool)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (true)
```

for the same reason.